# Mysql Select datetime, greater than timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to add a WHERE clause to my SELECT to get dates from my table WHERE the datetime in the table is greater than a passed in time stamp.

```
SELECT * FROM record WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(date_value, 'T', '')) >= 1388552400;
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| id     | date_value                   |
+--------+------------------------------+
| 344380 | 2014-12-01T00:00:00          |
| 344381 | 2014-12-23T00:00:00          |
| 344382 | 2014-12-16T00:00:00          |
| 344383 | 2014-12-24T00:00:00          |
| 344384 | 2014-12-17T00:00:00          | 
+--------+------------------------------+
```

I've tried a few things, but I either get an empty set or a waring of Incorrect datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the `T` in your `date_values` with a space, `' '` not an empty string, `''`.

So the following query should work as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM record WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(date_value, 'T', ' ')) >= 1388552400;
```

---

To debug your original query, I ran the following:

```
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(date_value, 'T', '')) FROM record;
```

which returned timestamps of all 0.

So then I followed with:

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(date_value, 'T', '') FROM record;
```

where I was able to see the missing space in your date_value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a184f/6

Comment: Ugh staring at that for an hour and didn't even realize it needed to be a space. Thanks!